# startActivityForResult() for ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE intent takes ~6 seconds

Tags: android, android-activity, bluetooth

I need to show the "Do you want to turn Bluetooth on?" dialog in my Android application.

For this purpose I just got the code from the [official android documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html).

From my activity OnCreate() method I do the following:

```
if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
    Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
    startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
}
```

**It works. But it takes ~6 seconds for the dialog to appear !**

Corresponding logcat:

```
01-06 06:53:04.789 I/ActivityManager(  313): START {act=android.bluetooth.adapter.action.REQUEST_ENABLE cmp=com.android.settings/.bluetooth.RequestPermissionActivity u=0} from pid 6512
01-06 06:53:04.812 I/ActivityManager(  313): START {act=com.android.settings.bluetooth.ACTION_INTERNAL_REQUEST_BT_ON cmp=com.android.settings/.bluetooth.RequestPermissionHelperActivity u=0} from pid 907
01-06 06:53:09.843 I/ActivityManager(  313): Displayed com.android.settings/.bluetooth.RequestPermissionActivity: +5s36ms (total +5s114ms)
01-06 06:53:09.843 I/ActivityManager(  313): Displayed com.android.settings/.bluetooth.RequestPermissionHelperActivity: +5s28ms
```

**What could be the reason for such an unusual slowness and how can I debug/fix it?**

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem could be here:

1. `onPause()`, `onStop()` or `onSaveInstanceState()` make heavy load.
2. Your application is using a lot of memory, so window manager wait for garbage collector
3. You make heavy load on service or asynchronous process
4. You fill IPC (Inter-process communication) memory, but probably this is not you reason.

I think your problem is probably the first. Try to check and tell us what you found.

Comment: "service or anysinchroniuos process" - do you mean "asynchronous", or something else?

Comment: I mean `asynchronous`. Sorry for mistyping.